# Java HTTP Post Applet server - Internally generated Image

Tags: java, http, post, applet, bufferedimage

I have a BufferedImage created using J2D in an applet.
I want to upload this BufferedImage using HTTP Post @ http://localhost:3001/upload/file.

EDIT: I have a ROR server handling the serverside of things, I am looking for the Java code for the client.

All the examples I can find involve uploading Files.

Anybody know how to upload a BufferedImage?

Cheers,

slotishtype

Comment: First result in google was this link http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-servlet/how-to-return-an-image-in-a-servlet.html

Comment: Yep, but that is servlet code.  I am looking for the client code that runs in the applet.  Good point though, I amended the question.

Comment: The answer to this question might be some help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577834/how-to-send-an-image-from-a-java-applet-to-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, So here is the code that creates the bufferedimage, encodes it as a Base64 string and then using the apache commons library posts the string over http to a ROR Server.

```
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(110, 110, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        AffineTransform saveTX = new AffineTransform();
        saveTX.translate(translateX, translateY);
        saveTX.scale(0.2, 0.2);
        g2.setTransform(saveTX);
        this.paint(g2);

        ImageInputStream bigInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(bi);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bi, "BMP", baos);
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String dataImg = new Base64().encodeBase64String(bytes);

        PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://localhost:3001/upload/file");

        post.addParameter("upload[test]", dataImg);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        int status = client.executeMethod(post);

        g2.dispose();
```

The ROR server simply takes the string, decodes it and saves it to the harddrive....

```
require "base64"
 class UploadController < ApplicationController

 #Token = nil
 skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token 

 def index
    render :file => 'app\views\upload\uploadfile.html.erb'
 end
 def file

File.open('test.gif', 'wb') do|f|
  f.write(Base64.decode64(params[:upload][:test]))
end

    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
 end
```

end

Thanks for the help guys,

slotishtype