# Sending an Image to a Java applet from Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, image, applet

Is it possible to send an Image object from JavaScript to an applet? Say I have a method in my applet like so:

```
public void setImage(Image newImage){
     trayIcon = new TrayIcon((new ImageIcon(path)).getImage());
}
```

and I'm calling said method from my javascript as:

```
applet.setImage(myImage);
```

Is there anyway I can send an Image as an Image object to Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an image from a Java Applet to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577834/how-to-send-an-image-from-a-java-applet-to-javascript)

Comment: @techdude It's similar but it appears to be the reverse of what I need. I know this might be a dumb question, but is the Image object `var img = new Image();` compatible with Java's Image object?

Comment: *"..is the Image object var img = new Image(); compatible with Java's Image object?"*  ..what happened when you *tried it?*